# How does ASP.NET page event handling work in the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may seem like a super basic question. But I had this interviewer ask me this.

How does the browser handle an event, say a button click in an ASP.NET page?

Comment: It's not basic, not at all! ASP.NET (Forms) goes to great lengths to ensure the programmer experience for controls events is "the same" as for desktop applications, and it has to do a lot of complex stuff to make that work. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/y3bwdsh3 for a high level overview. The short answer is "the page posts a request that says the button was pushed", but the full story (from page load to click to handle) is certainly something that deserves a long answer.

Answer (score 0):

the short answere is:

the button generated a PostBack where is capture from the web navigator.

regards